# В каких размерах делать приложение на xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, мобильная-разработка, мобильные-приложения

Впервые сталкиваюсь и с Xamarin, и с мобильной разработкой.

Перелопатил документацию и статьи, вот что получил:

1. dp == width_in_px * 160 / dpi
2. Есть понятие Screen Density. Например xhdpi, где 1dp == 2px

Я установил Xamarin Live Player. Беру свой Ipad Air2.

В google узнаю, что dpi == 264px на дюйм. Разрешение 2048x1536px. Вставляю в формулу и считаю:

width_in_dp == 2048 * 160 / 264. Это равняется 1241.

Задаю в AbsoluteLayout Label с точкой 0 0 и шириной в 1241px. Получаю более широкий элемент.

Нахожу device metrics от google, в них для ipad указано Screen Density xhdpi. 
C учётом новой информации делю и получаю 1024dp. И это подходит. https://material.io/devices/

И вот мой вопрос:

Почему первая формула является неправильной и по какому принципу разрабатываются приложения на Xamarin в плане размеров? Чтобы корректно отображалось на устройствах различных размеров?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AbsoluteLayout зло на любой платформе. Уже не знаю сколько лет везде твердят о том, что дизайн должен быть масштабируемым и т.д. 
Если ваша цель игры - узнавайте размеры устройства при старте и давайте перерасчеты всех позиций основываясь на этих данных. Во всех остальных случаях используйте только комбинацию из stacklayout, relative, grid и scroll. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/

Если у вас есть желание изменить дизайн при ооооочень большом экране (планшетник) делайте новый UI проект специально для него/ либо комбинируйте зависимости. для iOS такая функция есть в редакторе(к примеру в Xcode внизу можно выбрать определенное устройства и сделать расположение кнопок по нему)